# Get value from a dictionary string in Athena query

Tags: sql, json, presto, amazon-athena

I have an Athena DB table with the following two columns, I need to fetch name, gender and age from the 'user_data'

Structure:

```
id        - string
user_date - string
```

Data:

```
id   user_data                                                        
1    {'name': 'some_name', 'gender': 'male', 'age': '36'}
```

`user_data` is a dictionary string. Getting the values by casting it in to JSON:

```
CAST(user_data as JSON) as user_data_json
```

Then:

```
json_extract(user_data_json, '$.name') AS name
```

Since the dictionary string  is in single quotes the `CAST()` fails.

Also tried to replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
replace(user_data,'"',"'")
```

Then casting it in to JSON also failed:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:30: Column ''' cannot be resolved*

How to get those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `replace()` function; you cannot use double quotes instead of single quotes to declare a literal string - double quotes stand for identifiers (such as column names or table names), hence the error that you are getting.

To replace embedded single quotes with double quotes, you can do:

```
replace(user_data, '''', '"')
```

The rest of your code should just work:

```
select 
    json_extract(user_data_json, '$.name')   as name,
    json_extract(user_data_json, '$.gender') as gender,
    json_extract(user_data_json, '$.age')    as age
from (select id, replace(user_data, '''', '"') user_data from mytable) t
```